# USB Type-C as DRP

Tags: usb, usb-c

I am working on a design where I am using a phone type-c connector as a source to power my device by connecting two 5.1 resistors to the cc1 and cc2 pins. On the other end of the device, I am using another type-c female connector whose cc1 and cc2 pins are also connected to the 5.1 resistors. I am using a 3.3V LDO to power up my circuit. I am a little confused here. I want to know what will happen if my device is connected to the phone and I connect the charger. Will both work as a source to power up my device or only the charger will work as a source while charging the phone?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Both the charger and the phone will try to supply power into the same voltage rail and one of them might get damaged (likely the phone). Don't do that. CC to ground on a port = "I'm a sink, give me power".

Comment: How to solve this?

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday and you have the same answer there than here as a comment. If you ask what will happen if you do a circuit like this, you get an answer to that question. If you then ask how to solve this, we don't know what is the problem, what you want to do and how to solve it.